# subdomain with mvc godaddy hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-hosting

I've published my mvc app to godaddy (root, ie www.example.com) and all works great. Now I need to post some html files to a subdomain (ie subdomain.example.com) which I've set up. 
However now when I browse to subdomain.domain.com I get web.config error

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified." Line
>   101:       add
>   assembly="System.Web.Helpers,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /...

The only files in subdomain directory are html files. Why is web.config coming into play? I thought having a subdomain would separate these virtual directories (root and subdomain)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention these are .html files. Sure they're not .cshtml?

Domain oddities aside - your host doesn't have the "ASP.NET Webpages" System.Web.Helpers assembly in their GAC, or otherwise available for your deployment.

To solve this, you need to bin-deploy the assemblies. Start by creating a `bin` directory, and uploading the `System.Web.Helpers.dll` there.

You'll find it on your developer machine at somewhere like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Helpers.dll`

Comment: You may need to upload System.Web.Mvc.dll as well @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\

Answer (score 3):

I used [these instructions](http://help.godaddy.com/article/6639?locale=en) from the GoDaddy site to get mine working:

**To Deploy MVC3 Applications with Windows Hosting**

In your application's project, add references to the following assemblies:

1. Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
2. System.Web.Helpers
3. System.Web.Mvc
4. System.Web.Razor
5. System.Web.WebPages
6. System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
7. System.Web.WebPages.Razor

For each reference you just added, set the Copy Local property to True.
Deploy your application.

Comment: Thank you, Jason. Exactly what I was looking for. This equally applies to other similar hosting providers. This one-off effort is now paying off handsomely.